# Как сделать выполнение метода по событию Click?

Tags: c#, winforms, методы

Нужно, чтобы метод *questions* выполнялся по клику кнопки. 
При том, он должен выполняться в *printDocument1_PrintPage*. 
Заранее спасибо

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int currentPage = 1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        questions(e);
    }

    private void questions(PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        FileStream file = new FileStream("e:\\test.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
        string c = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] array = c.Split('\n');     
        reader.Close();
        Font font = new Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 15F,
                               System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
                               System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                             ((byte)(0)));
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;          
        StringFormat format1 = new StringFormat();
        format1.Trimming = StringTrimming.EllipsisWord;
        if (this.currentPage <= numericUpDown1.Value)
        {
            foreach (var item in array)
            {                 
                g.DrawString(item/*+ this.currentPage*/, font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,  new RectangleF(10, 10, 820, 1000), format1);
            }

            this.currentPage++;
            e.HasMorePages = true;
        }
        if (this.currentPage > numericUpDown1.Value)
        {
            currentPage = 1;
            e.HasMorePages = false;
        }

        printPreviewControl1.Rows = 20;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //this.printDocument1.Print();
    }        
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто при клике Button вызвать `questions` передав объект PrintPageEventArgs через конструктор [PrintPageEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printpageeventargs.printpageeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) с соответствующими аргументами.

Comment: так? https://pp.vk.me/c637728/v637728835/1ef3d/jkuIq23jN-w.jpg

Comment: уже пробовал это

Comment: @serverdevel и где же на вашем скрине вызов конструктора  `PrintPageEventArgs` ?

Comment: Вы не вызывали new PrintPageEventArgs на скриншоте.

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov если писать там PrintPageEventArgs, то выходит ошибка в desinger'e

Comment: @Vadim Ovchinnikov уже решил проблему

Comment: Выложите ответ как, может у кого-то возникнет подобная проблема.